# Unable to open KTR in Pentaho Community Edition 9.3 from repository

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have download Pentaho Community Edition 9.3 form sourceforge. I have created file based repository and I have few KTR and KJB in my repository. The issue is When I tried to open KTR from repository its not opening at all. no error message, nothing but KJB is working fine and KJB open without any issues. However I can open KTR using "reference objects from KJB". Anyone has a any idea about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use a repository with PDI? It works better and you save in headaches if you just use plain OS directories with the `${Internal.Entry.Current.Directory}` to refer to relative paths to other files (jobs and transformations) and doing all the control version in git.

Repositories in PDI didn't add much value unless you need to also use the Pentaho Server afterwards, and file repositories gave even more headaches than database repositories if I remember correctly, I think people where discourage to use them in the old forum.